# Repeated poor questions

Tags: discussion

Should there be some type of "delay loop" to control new user posts?

As this question has been posted weekly for several weeks and is closed each time: see [I didn’t get a raise. How can I cost my company 3% of my salary?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/153507/75821)

Comment: it got posted, got closed straight away, I got a laugh out of it.... whats the issue? Hopefully get another laugh next week.

Comment: At this point this is clearly spam so you should flag it as such. Spam posts are nuked automatically within a very short period of time and will help feed our automated systems. Note to anyone confused: variations on this question have been posted regularly lately. Most are gone within half a day so you may not have seen them.

Comment: @Lilienthal is this a repost of [this prior question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/153369/i-didn-t-get-a-raise)? under 10K rep I can't see

Comment: @gnat Yes, the title is slightly changed, but the question is identical.

Comment: thanks @PlayerOne! In this case, repost circumventing closure (and possibly also sock user account) look like stronger reasons to request for mod deletion. Lilienthal mentioned that it's spam, but per my recollection it was difficult to find reliable indication of that in the question (otherwise I would have flagged it:)

Comment: I see these questions as examples of the system working well at filtering out useless content without having any significant or direct impact on real people trying to ask real questions.

Comment: Don't worry, they've now moved on to asking [how to escape punishment for damaging company property](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/153570/did-something-immature-in-a-moment-of-anger-company-is-now-rechecking-cameras-t).

Comment: @BSMP yeah, just seen that...

Comment: @gnat Reason for flaging as spam is two-fold: to feed IP blocks, and because it will allow the community to remove these posts. As dwizum mentions the community is already handling this via closing and downvotes but it's still wasting people's time as long as the question remains on the front page. Cleaner to get rid of it or at least flag for our attention.

Comment: @Lilienthal I wouldn't object if moderator reflags as spam and deletes based on my custom flag :)