# Is there a way to inform the wider userbase about dealing with the troll?

Tags: discussion, trolling

Not all users drop into meta, and so many are likely not aware of the advice in the previous question about dealing with the troll. (do not engage and flag as spam)

This is leading to users engaging with the troll, which is exactly what the troll is seeking and fuelling further trolling.

Is there a way to get the message out to users who don't read meta q&a?

Comment: They could tag the other question as featured.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a satisfying answer to this. Somehow sending a broad message to the whole community about this would seem to play into the attention-seeking nature of the troll even more so than questions occasionally sitting long enough to trick users into interacting.

Comment: I agree with dwizum here, if you want to optimize anything it should be delete time not informing more people about it, attention is the goal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [That troll again, what can be done?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6637/that-troll-again-what-can-be-done)

Comment: @gnat not really - while it does have excellent advice on how to deal with the troll, it doesn't explain how to get that information to users who don't frequent meta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tagging one of the relevant meta posts as featured is probably somewhat effective, as is crafting a pro forma comment or post notice to put on the offending posts so others get an opportunity to get educated.

I will propose and start using:

> This is a troll question.  Do not engage or waste effort on voting to close, flag as spam and move on.  [See Meta](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6622/addressing-the-troll-in-the-room) for more.